# URLS Friendly Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a web under Wordpress with URL Post friendly: Permalink

But I add a aditional PHP pages.

```
<?php
if($_REQUEST['page'] == 'register' || $_REQUEST['page'] == 'login')
{
    include (TEMPLATEPATH . "/library/includes/registration.php");
}
elseif($_REQUEST['page'] == 'ads')
{
    include (TEMPLATEPATH . "/library/includes/tpl_createclassified.php");
} .....
```

Nowm the URL is:  mydomain.com/?page=ads and I want mydomain.com/ads or mydomain.com/ads/

How can I do it?

Exist any pluginn for that?

Thanks

Comment: You're looking for [Pretty Permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Permalinks).

Comment: No. I use Pretty Permaling from WP-Admin, and that´s good for the POST but I have some files (see the php code), and I need Friendly EO for that.

Comment: Files, or WordPress Pages?  If you've got Pretty Permalinks turned on, and your `.htaccess` file is set up correctly, then your Pages should be using Pretty Permalinks too.

Comment: No. Wordpress pages not. Customize php files